# Permission denied: .gvfs

Tags: roslaunch, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when using roslaunch tab completion on Ubuntu 13.04 and Hydro I receive:

[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /home/dereck: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/home/dereck/.gvfs"

This system was installed from scratch today, any ideas?

--

ls shows some weird permissions:
d?????????  ? ?      ?         ?            ? .gvfs/

Can't delete the directory even as root.

--

I rebooted and logged in via ssh, I was able to delete it and the permissions were normal. Something is causing ruckus when I log in to the desktop it seems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76896/permission-denied:-.gvfs/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-06

Post score: 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it like this (on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
#umount /home/useraccount/.gvfs
#rm -rf .gvfs/
```

hope that helped! :)

---

Originally posted by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) with karma: 706 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 66

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2014-09-29**:
Perfect fix. I don't have this problem anymore. Thanks

**Comment by [mmedonis](https://answers.ros.org/users/20742/mmedonis/) on 2014-11-08**:
Worked for me too. Thanks!

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2014-11-20**:
sudo umount /home/**$USER**/.gvfs

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2014-12-11**:
This worked for me too. Could you explain better what we have done? Thanks.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2014-12-16**:
We have unmounted the Gnome virtual file system and deleted the mounting point.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-10-27**:
Is this a good solution in case I'm using a distributed system with multiple machines?

**Comment by [zcam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26960/zcam/) on 2016-05-23**:
Yeah, stackoverflow doesn't really solve this. It only tell you to umount `/run/user/1000/gvfs` and remove ~/.gvfs. Which doesn't help. But this one is rock!

**Comment by [ZQ.Jones](https://answers.ros.org/users/28254/zq.jones/) on 2016-12-25**:
perfect solution! remember to omit '#' though.

**Comment by [emigmo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28503/emigmo/) on 2017-01-02**:
sudo umount /home//.gvfs
sudo rm  -rf  /home//.gvfs

**Comment by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on 2018-04-17**:
I tried this solution, the I got the following:
ysu66@mech1331:~$ umount /home/ysu66/.gvfs
umount: /home/ysu66/.gvfs is not in the fstab (and you are not root)
Can anyone help?

**Comment by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on 2018-04-17**:
Hi all, problem solved by adding sudo in the front. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reboot seemed to fix it... *shrug*

And now it's back, rebooting doesn't affect it... ? I've re-installed U13.04 now too...

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-18**:
Do you by any chance have an android device that you connect to you computer and after you did that once, this error appears?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-18**:
I don't think so, but I suppose it's possible.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-18**:
Might also be something else accessed via .gvfs. I suspect the completion tries to scan all directories (for some reason) and hits this one with an error.

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-18**:
Any way to make it go away? I've been Googling about for a while without too much luck. :/

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-18**:
From the non-ROS side, I had to unmount a broken mount that I mounted before - in my case an android device. I'm not sure if there are any tools to find out what this might be. From the ROS side, one could consider that warning a bug or feature. Is your home in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?